# class binding and ngClass not working in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

My template is :

```
<div [class.special]="scrollOnTop" ></div>
```

My class has this public property named "scrollOnTop" which can change depending on the scroll event.

My Class:

```
export class AppComponent {
constructor() {
    console.log("class initiated with constructor");
    this.scrollOnTop = true;
};

public scrollOnTop: boolean;

onScroll(event){
    console.log("scroll event", event);
    if(event.belowTop){
        this.scrollOnTop = false;
        console.log("scroll on top is - " + this.scrollOnTop)
    }else{
        this.scrollOnTop = true;
        console.log("scroll on top is - " + this.scrollOnTop)
    }
}
};
```

The div has "special" class when the template is rendered. But if the property "scrollOnTop" changes to false, the "special" class is not removed.

Please help

Comment: From where is `onScrollEvent()` called?

Comment: onScroll function is working fine, as I am checking the log. This event is emmited from a directive which checks the window.scroll event

Comment: It still is relevant how it is called. If it is called within Angulars zone or not. If you are listening to `window.onScroll` you can try the suggestion I added to my updated answer.

Comment: But scrollOnTop is being updated with scroll. I am not getting this concept of zoning in angular2. Can you provide me any reference?

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html, http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2. If Angular doesn't recognize that it needs to run change detection, then it doesn't matter if the value changed, Angular won't update the view.

Comment: Thanks guys, both @Thierry Templier and Gunter. Thanks for helping me out. Also, now I know amazing concept of zone in Angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

```
export class AppComponent { 
  @HostBinding('window:scroll, ['$event'])
  onScroll(event){
    ..
  }
}
```

**original**

I guess this is caused by the way you set `scrollOnTop`.

Ensure the assignment is don't in Angulars zone:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

  someMethod() {

    ...
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.scrollOnTop = someValue;
    });
    ...

  }
}
```

Comment: I am confused...Do you want me to implement above code? I think putting in zone would cause problem. I am not very familiar with zone

Comment: It's just a guess. Please provide more information about how you set `scrollOntop`. I think my suggestion above is worth a try, to know if this fixes your problem and then to check what actually caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ngClass` instead:

```
<div [ngClass]="{special: scrollOnTop}" ></div>
```

The `scrollOnTop` property is a boolean. If true, the `special` class is added and if false removed.

Comment: If the `scrollOnTop` actually updated? Could you add the code that updates its value? Thanks!

Comment: How the `onScroll` method is called?

Comment: onScroll method is called from an event. This event is being fired from a directive which checks the window.onScroll event. This methhod is working fine as I can see the logs

Comment: I think that the issue is what Günter said. Is the method executed within a zone? If not you will see the update in your trace but Angular2 can't detect it. Could you try to wrap the update of the `scrollOnTop` property into a `run` method as he pointed out?

Comment: Please provide me a reference to read this concept, as I don't know how zoning works in angular2.

Comment: It's handled under the hood. By default there is nothing to do except for objects that are instantiated outside Angular2. In your case, the object that triggers the event isn't managed by Angular2 so it's executed outside a zone. To explicitly execute into a zone, simply inject the `NgZone` object and execute your code into the callback you provide in its `run` method...

Comment: yes, i would suggest using ngClass instead of [class.someclass] = propertyname | ""

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the following article from the author and it covers almost all declaration types of styling in Angular2

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/